# Error when instantiating i2c slave device

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, i2c

Hello I am trying to create an i2c slave device on my beaglebone black(debian 10) which is running the kernel version 4.19.94-ti-r42.I was going to implement my own i2c slave device driver by writing my own kernel module but then i cam across a command that i think would allow me to instantiate a slave device on the i2c bus 2 without having to do any of that.I used the following command to do this:

```
echo slave-24c02 0x1064 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/new_device
```

which i got from the following site: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/slave-interface.html

yet when i ran the command i got the following error:

```
-bash: /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/new_slavedevice: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know what i may be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `sudo`?  Member of `group`?

Comment: i tried using 'sudo' but it did not work. What do you mean by group?

Comment: Why do you need this at all?! Describe properly your slave device (EEPROM) in Device Tree or ACPI.

Comment: So i would need to create my own deivce driver for an i2c slave?

Comment: my end goal is to have the beaglebone black be the slave to the raspberry pi as the master

Comment: Then You have to make your host controller on BBB to be slave first!

Comment: @andriy thats what im trying to do and i thought that in order to do that i would have set up a device driver or by using a command similar to the one i posted above. However i cant seem to find anything online that conclusively describes how to make the BBB a slave

Comment: Redirecting the output of a `sudo` command to a file requires the user to have write access on the file. A workaround is to embed the redirection into the command arguments passed to `sudo` like this: `sudo sh -c 'echo slave-24c02 0x1064 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/new_device'`

Answer (score 0):

Are u trying to instantiate a i2c-slave(i.e access the eeprom device), or custom "linux-i2c-slave"  to handle the read/write for that address.

I presume that you are using beaglebox, and want to instantiate eeprom device on it from linux.

In that case, you need an i2c-slave, and the command would be

> ```
> echo 24c02 0x1064 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/new_device
> ```

Hope I have understood the question correctly.